# Cant remember the state of toggle button in a listview

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to remember the state of the toggle button in a listview whenever i pressed the toggle button.

I tried using shared preferences to remember the toggle button state based on the item position but it did not work. However i think theres a problem doing so as if i delete one of the item from the listview, the position might get changed.

```
// getting the toggle button state using shared preference
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
Boolean runstopChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_runstop", false);
viewHolder.tbtnJobRunStop.setChecked(runstopChecked);
```

```
// Saving the position and toggle button state
viewHolder.tbtnJobRunStop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("pref_runstopposition", position);
                if(isChecked) 
                {
                    runJobId = dataModel.getJobId();
                    editor.putBoolean("pref_runstop", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    Intent statusIntent = new Intent(getContext(), RefreshJobService.class);
                    statusIntent.putExtra("id", runJobId);
                    getContext().startService(statusIntent);
                } else 
                {
                    stopJobId = dataModel.getJobId();
                    editor.putBoolean("pref_runstop", false);
                    editor.apply();
                    stopJob stopjob = new stopJob();
                    stopjob.execute();
                    Intent i = new Intent("stopjob");
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
                    i.putExtra("stopJobId",stopJobId);
                    getContext().sendBroadcast(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong you should create another ArrayList in which you will store all the clicked buttons position in the listview. And, in onBindViewHolder method, you have to check if the ArrayList contains a particular position, if yes set the button state pressed or unpressed.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

pass a List of models to your listview and the model will contain the values and checked tag

```
    public class MyPojo{
    private String myValue="";
    private boolean isChecked = false;

   // set your getter and setter here 
}
```

in your viewHolder of your listview check if the item.isChecked true make toggle on else false when the toggle checked set isChecked of the current position as true else set false  if you want to save the status of your list better to use DB maybe Room or ObjectBox because sharedPrefernce use for only one value